# inheriting constructors (ISO 2011 sec 12.9 para 7)

Tags: c++, c++11, gcc, constructor, inheriting-constructors

I am trying out example from ISO 2011 sec 12.9 para 7.Follwing is the code i am tring to compile

```
int chk;
struct B1 {   B1(int){chk=9;} };
struct B2 {   B2(int){chk=10;} };
struct D2 : B1, B2 {
       using B1::B1;
       using B2::B2;
      D2(int){chk=0;};  
};
int main(){
  B1 b(9);
  D2 d(0);
  return 0;
}
```

$g++ -std=c++11 sample.cpp
Error message

```
 <source>: In constructor 'D2::D2(int)': <source>:7:10: error: no matching function for call to 'B1::B1()'    D2(int){chk=0;};
      ^ <source>:2:15: note: candidate: B1::B1(int)  struct B1 {   B1(int){chk=9;} };
           ^~ <source>:2:15: note:   candidate expects 1 argument, 0 provided <source>:2:8: note: candidate: constexpr B1::B1(const B1&)  struct B1 {   B1(int){chk=9;} };
    ^~ <source>:2:8: note:   candidate expects 1 argument, 0 provided <source>:2:8: note: candidate: constexpr B1::B1(B1&&) <source>:2:8: note:   candidate expects 1 argument, 0 provided <source>:7:10: error: no matching function for call to 'B2::B2()'    D2(int){chk=0;};
      ^ <source>:3:15: note: candidate: B2::B2(int)  struct B2 {   B2(int){chk=10;} };
           ^~ <source>:3:15: note:   candidate expects 1 argument, 0 provided <source>:3:8: note: candidate: constexpr B2::B2(const B2&)  struct B2 {   B2(int){chk=10;} };
    ^~ <source>:3:8: note:   candidate expects 1 argument, 0 provided <source>:3:8: note: candidate: constexpr B2::B2(B2&&) <source>:3:8: note:   candidate expects 1 argument, 0 provided Compiler exited with result code 1
```

Is this a bug in gcc?Why is it looking for B1()?I am using gcc 6.3.0

Editing:
QUestion in linked question is about when one base class is used.i.e following code

```
int chk;
struct B1 {   B1(int){chk=9;} };
//struct B2 {   B2(int){chk=10;} };
struct D2 : B1  {
   using B1::B1;
  //using B2::B2;
  //D2(int){chk=0;};  
 };
int main(){
   B1 b(9);
   D2 d(0);
   return 0;
}
```

Which is working but when D2(int){chk=0;} is introduced thats when the error occurs.

Answer (score 0):

In `D`, you provide the sole constructor `D2(int){chk=0;}`, which does not explicitly call any of the constructors of base classes `B1` and `B2`. Hence, the compiler looks for a default constructor in `B1` and `B2`, which would be implicitly called. But your base structures `B1` and `B2` do not provide a default constructor...

Hence, either define default constructors in `B1` and `B2`, or call the other constructors explicitly in an initialiser list of `D`'s constructor:

```
D2(int x):B1(x),B2(x) {chk=0;};
```

Comment: I have changed code as follows   `int chk;struct B1 {   B1(int){chk=9;} };
struct B2 {   B2(double,float){chk=10;} };
struct D2 : B1,B2 {
       using B1::B1;
       using B2::B2;
       //D2(){}
     // D2(int){chk=0;};  
};
int main(){
  B1 b(9);
 D2 d(10);
  return 0;
}`     I am still getting the error.In this case it says constructor inherited by 'D2' from base class 'B1' is implicitly deleted.Why is it being deleted?I am trying to find this particular rule about default constructors from ISO doc.Can you point reference to ISO doc? @Stephan Lechner